# Importing class from another package

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
F:.
│   .gitignore
│
└───Tests
    │   main.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───compare
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   └───process
    │           process.py
    │           __init__.py
    │
    ├───lookup
    │       User.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───requestor
    │       Requestor.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───search
    │       UserSearch.py
    │       ProductSearch.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───utils
            constants.py
            __init__.py
```

I am able to import any file/class from `main.py` like

```
from search.UsersSearch import UsersSearchPayLoad
from search.ProductSearch import ProductSearchPayLoad
from utils.constants import *
```

but I cannot do any import from any other package like, from `search.UserSearch`:

```
from ..utils.constants import *
from Tests.utils.constants import *
```

I was referring [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) for understanding the correct way to use relative imports.

I am using Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.getcwd()))
```

In:
**`Tests/__init__.py`**

Comment: I added this line and `from ..utils.constants import *` works in `search` and `from ...utils.constants import *` works in `compare.process`. Or should I use `import Tests.utils.constants`. 'cause both are working??

Comment: That's just fine. I would like you to watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0 it helps a lot understand everything about modules, paths, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest phython Version e.g 3.7.0

```
from directory import class-name
```

A directory is your folder structure. It could be subDirectory\directory